# Поиск максимального(минимального) значения типа данных Char

Tags: java, char

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Мне надо написать метод который выводит минимальное цифровое значение типа данных `char(0)` и такой же метод для вывода максимального значения(65535). Методами и полями класса Character (как Min_Value) и другими вариантами из библиотеки пользоваться нельзя.

Вот пример кода для вывода максимального и минимального цифрового значения типа данных `byte`, подобно надо реализовать и для `char`, но не понимаю как прописать условие выхода из цикла. Да и с приведением из `char` в `int` и наоборот, видно, запутался.

```
private static byte maxValByte () {
    byte temp = 1;
    while (temp > 0) {
        temp *= 2;
    }
    return (byte) (temp - 1);
}

private static byte minValByte () {
    byte temp = 1;
    while (temp > 0) {
        temp *= 2;
    }
    return (byte) (temp);
}
```

Не могли бы подсказать какой тут алгоритм решения?

Comment: Например `char c = (char)65535`.

Comment: Возможно [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23413497/how-to-print-max-value-of-character) вашей проблемы.

Answer (score 3):

`char` - беззнаковый тип, ему нельзя присвоить отрицательные значения. Поэтому можно считать его минимальным значением 0, а максимальное можно получить, присвоив ему -1:

```
char c = (char)-1;
System.out.println((int)c);
```

Результат в консоли: 65535.

Answer (score 0):

Для перевода `int` в `char` и обратно вы можете использовать `(int)` и `(char)`

```java
int var1 = 1;
char var2 = 'a';

(int)var2
(char)var1
```

---

У вас в цикле условие `while (temp > 0)`, а в теле вы удваиваете значение `temp`. Учитывая, что значение `temp` изначально равно единице, то цикл никогда не закончится

---

Также, не совсем понятно условие задачи.

Вам нужно найти минимально и максимально возможные значения `int`, которые могут быть конвертированы в `char`, но пользоваться константами `Character.MAX_VALUE` и `Character.MIN_VALUE` нельзя. В чем тогда суть задачи?

Минимальное значение можно считать как ноль. Для получения максимального значения вы может подставить `-1`, как сказал пользователь`@Имя_Фамилия`

Comment: в приведенном примере переменная типа byte, на восьмой итерации цикла она станет равна -128 что и будет условием выхода из цикла. 
За совет по чару большое спасибо